# OpenLDAP No such object (32)

Tags: ldap, openldap

I am trying to setup an OpenLDAP server with FusionDirectory as a frontend

Following this guide: 
http://documentation.fusiondirectory.org/en/documentation/admin_installation_redhat_6

http://documentation.fusiondirectory.org/openldap_install_rhel6

I have the following in my ch_domainSettings.ldif

```
dn: olcDatabase={1}monitor,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcAccess
olcAccess: {0}to * by   dn.base="gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth"
  read by dn.base="cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=net" read by * none

dn: olcDatabase={2}bdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcSuffix
olcSuffix: dc=example,dc=net

dn: olcDatabase={2}bdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcRootDN
olcRootDN: cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=net

dn: olcDatabase={2}bdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcRootPW
olcRootPW: {SSHA}RbncgBcs8McqwMMAjx4CFdENpLycUc4w

dn: olcDatabase={2}bdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcAccess
olcAccess: {0}to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange by
  dn="cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=net" write by anonymous auth by self write by * none
olcAccess: {1}to dn.base="" by * read
olcAccess: {2}to * by dn="cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=net" write   by * read
```

And when run

```
Sudo ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f ch_domainSettings.ldif
```

I get the following error:

```
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
modifying entry "olcDatabase={1}monitor,cn=config"

modifying entry "olcDatabase={2}bdb,cn=config"
ldap_modify: No such object (32)
        matched DN: cn=config
```

Can you please indicate as to what could be wrong?

Answer (score 11):

You need to find out what backend databases you have configured:

```
ldapsearch -H ldapi:/// -Y EXTERNAL -b "cn=config" -LLL -Q "olcDatabase=*" dn
```

The one you're looking for could be BDB, HDB or MDB.

(EDIT : one more /)

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps your second configured database isn't of the type `bdb`. For instance, CentOS 7 uses `hdb` by default.

```
dn: olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
```